# VueJS2 how to dynamically emit event to parent component?

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

just like the title i need to dynamically emit an event to parent component's methods, i have a component structured like this

```
<TableComponent 
  :actionmenus="actionmenus"
  @edit="parenteditmethod"
  @delete="parentdeletemethod">
</TableComponent>
```

here is actionmenus object

```
actionmenus: [
  {title: 'Edit', emitevent: 'edit'},
  {title: 'Delete', emitevent: 'delete'}
]
```

and then here is snippet of my tablecomponent

```
...
<ul>
  <li v-for="menu in actionmenus"><a @click="$emit(menu.emitevent)" class="text-menu">{{ menu.title }}</a></li>
</ul>
...
```

i know this should be easily done by `$emit('edit')` or `$emit('delete')` without using actionmenus object but the `$emit()` part should be dynamic based on the passed array actionmenus so that the tablecomponent can be re-used on different case. how should i approaching this? is there any way?

Comment: Your code works, what's the problem?

Comment: @CodinCat event is not emitted. i wonder is `@click="$emit(menu.emitevent)"` really the right way to pass variable to emit function.

Comment: It does work, see the example: https://codepen.io/CodinCat/pen/eWRoeb

Comment: you are right, i see my error is in my css file. the parent of ul element visibility is shown by using focus on an element, when i tried to click the link, parent element focus is loss and the ul element visibility is hidden before handling the click event. i fix this by using delay in the visibility transition. i hope my explanation is clear enough so that everyone who has same problem with me can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you would like to emit an event from the child component to the parent, and pass some data with the emit (sorry if thats not the case).

As you know, you can emit events in the child component like this :

```
$emit("EVENT");
```

And Catch it in the parent like this :

`<childTag v-on:EVENT="parentFunction"></childTag`>

You can also pass data to the parent from the child like this :

```
$emit("EVENT",DATA);
```

And catch the data in the parent function like this

```
<childTag v-on:EVENT="parentFunction"></childTag>
...
methods{
  parentFunction(DATA){
    //Handle the DATA object from the child
  }
}
```

Hope this helps and best of luck!

Comment: yups! that's exactly what i am trying to do. but somehow have an issue with the event not emitted to the parent as i described on my comment above. your answer is shown how exactly to emit event to parent component in vuejs. may be i should accept this as an answer in order people navigated here because of my question title.

Comment: This solution assumes you know the name of the event? What about dynamically capturing and sending events to the parent?

Answer (score 0):

[@codincat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2739078/codincat) is right, that it all works. It's true also for Vue3

```js
const rootComponent = {
  el: "#app",
  data: function () {
    return {
      actionmenus: [
        { title: "Edit", emitevent: "edit" },
        { title: "Delete", emitevent: "delete" }
      ]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    parenteditmethod() {
      console.log("edit");
    },
    parentdeletemethod() {
      console.log("delete");
    }
  }
};

const app = Vue.createApp(rootComponent);
app.component("table-component", {
  props: { actionmenus: Array },
  template: `
    <ul>
      <li v-for="menu in actionmenus">
        <a @click="$emit(menu.emitevent)" class="text-menu">{{ menu.title }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>`
});

const rootComponentInstance = app.mount("#app");
```

```html
<!-- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43750969/vuejs2-how-to-dynamically-emit-event-to-parent-component -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/3.2.29/vue.global.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <table-component :actionmenus="actionmenus" @edit="parenteditmethod" @delete="parentdeletemethod">
  </table-component>
</div>
```